# Python code has incorrect directory, how do I fix

Tags: python, server, tcp, connection, client

I'm having some issues with a code I'm writing for class (a server client connection that transfers files to and from a client and server folder in my downloads). I've spent about 10 hours debugging and started over with a refresh of the code all together. The new code will be down below. some comments are technically questions, but the main two are 1) how do you make windows/python recognize the directory (I run it and says the directory doesn't exist.) 2) even if the directory was solved, the password system doesn't work either. How would I get it to work with the dictionary named.(Indents are correct, stackoverflow wanted indents placed)

Client Code:
import socket               # Import socket module

```
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.
x = True


username = input('Username: ')
password = input('Password: ')

Login = {
    "joshua": "macOS", #regardless of information used to login, still logs you in
    "scotto": "linux",
    "divetta": "windows",
    }

print("testing1") #prints but crashes too quickly

print("Successfully Logged In")
s.connect((host, port))
choice = int(input("1=Upload or 2=Download: "))
while x == True:
    if choice == 1:
        print("upload")
        upload = input("File name to upload: ")
        f = open('Client\\{upload}','rb') #ask about how to get folder to work here with filename
        print('Sending...')
        l = f.read(1024) #ask if this will make the file transfer, transfer data
        while (l):
            print('Sending...')
            s.send(l)
            l = f.read(1024)
            x = False
        f.close()
        print("Done Sending")
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        print(s.recv(1024))
        s.close()
        
elif choice == 2:
    print("download")
    download = input("File name to download: ")
    f = open('Client\\{download}','rb') #ask about how to get folder to work here with filename
    print('Receiving...')
    l = f.write(1024)
    while (l):
        print('Receiving...')
        s.recv(l)
        l = f.write(1024)
        x = False
    f.close()
    print("Done Receiving")
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print(s.recv(1024))
    s.close()
        
else:
    print("invalid choice")
    x = True`
```

Server Code:
import socket               # Import socket module

```
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
print('Got connection from', addr)

Login = {
    "joshua": "macOS",
    "scotto": "linux",
    "divetta": "windows",
    }

while True:
    l = c.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        print("Receiving...")
        f.write(l)
        l = c.recv(1024)
        f.close()
        print("Done Receiving")
        #c.close()                # Close the connection
while False:
    l = c.send(1024)
    while (l):
        print("Sending...")
        f.read(l)
        l = c.send(1024)
        f.close()
        print("Done Sending")
        #c.close()`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyr4C.png)

Tried debugging and redoing the code all together. Tried functions but would like to stay clear as it is a little too complicated for me.

Comment: `open` expects a file path and not whatever `"Client\\{download}}"` is supposed to be. Perhaps reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) might help.

Comment: This was closed as the wrong duplicate.  It is really a typo (missing `f` on a string that should be an f-string).  Voting to close as a typo instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues here:

- First off, you need to use f-strings if you want to use a variable in a string.

  If you check the error message, it tells you that it's trying to find a file literally called `Client\\{upload}`. Obviously, such a file doesn't exist. What you actually want is for the value of `upload` to be inserted into the string i.e. if `upload` is `some_file.txt`, it should try to open the file `Client\\some_file.txt`.

  To achieve this, you can use f-strings: `f"Client\\{upload}"`. Notice the `f` before the starting quotes, it's important and causes Python to replace `{upload}` with the value of the `upload` variable.
- Second, in the download case, you are opening the file for reading (`open(..., 'rb')`, the `r` stands for `read`) but you are writing to the file and hence need to open it for writing using `open(..., 'wb')`.
- Thirdly, the `elif choice == 2` case is indented incorrectly, on a different level than the matching `if` above it.
- And your server code seems completely broken in general, I can't even really tell how it's supposed to work. You're doing stuff on a file `f` that was never declared, you have a `while False` loop which makes no sense (that means, "never run this code"), you are receiving from and sending to the same socket. Also, what's the point of the `while True` loop anyways?

I'll also point out some style issues:

- `while (l)` -> `while l`
- Instead of `f = open(..)` and then later `f.close()`, you should pretty much always use:

  ```
  with open(..) as f:
    ...
    f.read() # or f.write()
    ...
  ```

  Python will automatically close the file at the end of the `with` block, even if an exception is thrown inside it, which isn't the case if you manually call `f.close()`.
- `x == True` is just the same thing as `x` if `x` can only be `True` or `False`.
- `x` is a terrible name for a variable that isn't an x-coordinate or has a very tiny scope, it doesn't tell me anything about what it actually means. The same applies to `l`, actually, you should never use `l` as a variable name ever since it can be indistinguishable from `1` or `I` in some fonts. `s` and `f` are reasonably fine since they are easily recognizable as "socket" and "file" from how they are initialized and are commonly used that way.